# String comparison with QuickConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to do something when Idea.Status=="Verified" but QuickConverter ([1](http://blog.danskingdom.com/dont-write-wpf-converters-write-c-inline-in-your-xaml-instead-using-quickconverter/) - [2](https://quickconverter.codeplex.com/)) doesn't allow me to use any of these:

```
Binding="{qc:Binding '$P==Verified',P={Binding Path=Idea.Status}}"
Binding="{qc:Binding '$P=="Verified"',P={Binding Path=Idea.Status}}"
```

> 'Verified' is an unexpected token.  Expecting white space.
>
> Failed to tokenize expression "$P=Verified". Did you forget a '$'?

How can I tell quickconverter and XAML that I want to compare against a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it this way. It works the same as the chosen answer, but the xaml parser is much happier and doesn't throw annoyng (fake) errors

```
Binding="{Path=Idea.Status, Converter={qc:QuickConverter '$P == \'Verified\''}}"
```

Answer (score 9):

QuickConverter uses single quote for string literals. However within the markup extension you need to escape the single quote, so you need to add \ before it.

So your binding should be

```
Binding="{qc:Binding '$P==\'Verified\'',P={Binding Path=Idea.Status}}"
```

Comment: It works, the xaml parser throws the error "Markup extension is not properly closes", but it compiles and works

Comment: I need to wait 3 hours to award the bounty

Answer (score 2):

The only way i can came up with is by using the `qc:MultiBinding`

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Hi There !"  VerticalAlignment=" Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{qc:MultiBinding '$P0 == $P1', P0={Binding Status}, P1={Binding Verified}}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

`Verified` is defined as a property in the ViewModel/CodeBehind

```
public String Verified { get; set; }
```

here the full code behind

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String Verified = "Verified";

    private String _status = "Verified";
    public String Status
    {
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_status == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _status = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```